# Difference between rgba background and gif pixel repeated background

Tags: google-chrome, colors

A red and green .png logo is supposed to only reveal its red or green part, respectively, when scrolling on top of a red/green backgrounded area. Green part hides on green bg and red on red.

This works everywhere but on Chrome:
It does show a green stroke on the green logo part when on the green background.

See here ärztepraxis.at (umlaut-free: http://xn--rztepraxis-p5a.at/)

What helps? Someone suggested repeating a green pixel instead of the hex or rgb coloring.

Reference: green:7b003b red:81a996

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the resize algorithm being used, you need to change it in order to get rid of the outline. You can use the following CSS:

```
#null img {
    image-rendering: optimize-contrast;
    image-rendering: -webkit-optimize-contrast;
}
```

More information can be found in this article: http://www.danolsavsky.com/article-images-interpolation-browser-rendering-and-css-resizing.html